# F3 source code navigation stopped working for .xhtml files in Eclipse Indigo when using JSF 2.x

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I have just switched from Java Server Faces JSF 1.x to JSF 2.x. Files are now .xhtml instead of .jsp.

Suddenly, F3 source code navigation stopped working for xhtml files. Talking about something like this:

h:commandLink action="#{Preset.add}"...

When I navigate to Preset.add and press F3, Eclipse used to take me to Preset.java class, but now this doesn't work any more.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [JBoss tools plugin](http://www.jboss.org/tools). Go to *Help > Install New Software* and enter the following URL:

> http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/

In the list, just pick "JBoss Web and Java EE Development" option (others are not required). This offers among others Ctrl+Click and F3 navigation.

Comment: Do I just pick "JBoss Tools JSF" subcomponent or the whole "JBoss Web and Java EE Development"?

Comment: Ok, I installed only subcomponent.
Very nice to have more editors available now. Thank you for the advice. However, I still can't open managed bean class when I press F3 in the xhtml editor. Is that supposed to work after this addon? Thx.

Comment: I have installed the whole "JBoss Web and Java EE Development". It works at least for me. See also http://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/jst/jst-news-3.3.0.M3.html

Comment: Suddenly started working! Maybe because I executed "Project->Configuration->Add JSF Capability"? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that link explicitely says: "JSF Tools now support managed beans annotated @ManagedBean." So, it must work - and it works. Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated to JBoss Tools to Beta1 and it started crashing my Eclipse 7.1. Also it can't visualy show many xhtml files, only white empty page is shown instead. Do you have any info on this?

Comment: Switched back to M5 release, and it works again. Maybe you try Beta1 or Beta 3 (the latest) in Eclipse 7.2?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Haven't upgraded to Beta1 yet. I'm not the JBoss Tools developer, you might want to report your problem to them.

Comment: Will do. Just wanted to confirm that it's not my system that couses the problem.